# Updating BLOB field from $_POST making the BLOB value 0 Bytes Long

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a peculiar behavior (peculiar as far as I've experienced) updating a BLOB field in an existing MySql record.  When I update it, the blob value becomes empty - the field is not NULL, but the blob in the field is 0 bytes long.

```
extract($_POST);
$bio = $_POST['bio']
$cleanBio = addslashes($bio); 
$sql = 'UPDATE people 
    SET biography = :bio
    WHERE client_index = :id';
$db->query($sql);
$db->bind(array('bio', $cleanBio));
$db->bind('id', $id);
$db->execute();
```

I've tested a few things:

1. I inserted the biography manually (ex: in a direct sql query in phpmyadmin or terminal, etc) - success!
2. I created a variable on the page itself with the same contents that is in the POST variable (but not assigning it from the POST var - just manually doing it on the page to test) - success!
3. I put the variables in the query itself (vs. binding) with the $_POST var - failed...
4. I made the biography data a short simple sentence (ex: "I like pizza") but passed it in the $_POST var - failed...

The original insert of the record (with data in the blob) successfully inserts. It's only the update that's creating this problem.

Anyone out there have any ideas on what may be causing this?  Thanks!

UPDATE:
This seems to be happening whether the field is a blob or a varchar...

Form that submits the data:

```
<form name=bioForm id=bioForm action=bioTest2.php method=POST>
<textarea name=bio id=bio class=textinput>
</textarea>
<input type=submit class=generalButton value="Save">
</form>
```

Here's a stripped down version of the $db class:

```
class Database2 {
    private $dbh;
    private $errorMsg;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . MYHOST . ";dbname=" . MYDB . ";charset=utf8";
        $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, MYUSER, MYPASS, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function query($sql) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }
    public function bind($valuesArray) {
        foreach($valuesArray AS $placeholder=>$value) {
            $this->stmt->bindValue($placeholder, $value);
        }
    }
    public function resultSet() {
        $this->stmt->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function single(){
        $this->stmt->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function execute() {
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

> UPDATE:  Below, there's a record from the mysql log.  It looks like
>   the query is running twice (though I'm only calling it once - have
>   triple-checked it!). The second one (91) has the empty value for bio. 
>   Any idea what might be causing this?
>
> 89 Query     UPDATE people
>                   SET biography = 'this is a test string' WHERE client_index = 6
>
> 91 Query     UPDATE clients
>                   SET biography = '' WHERE client_index = 6

Comment: which class's object $db have?

Comment: $db is simply a PDO object

Comment: Can you please add HTML Form which you are using

Comment: change $db->bind(array('bio', $cleanBio)); to $db->bind(array(':bio'=>$cleanBio));
 use same thing to bind id

Comment: Chetan - thanks for the hint but the bind call requires the ':' to be left out.  Other updates (ex: updates of other fields) work correctly with the syntax in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the FORM method please check the form method make sure it will be POST method.

Or use `$_REQUEST` instead of the `$_POST` It will work

There is nothing wrong with the your SQL query.

```
extract($_REQUEST);
$bio = $_REQUEST['bio']
$cleanBio = mysql_real_escape_string($bio); 
$sql = 'UPDATE people 
    SET biography = :bio
    WHERE client_index = :id';
$db->query($sql);
$db->bind(array('bio' => $cleanBio , 'id' => $id));
$db->execute();
```

Comment: Tried the $_REQUEST option just for kicks, but I get the same behavior.  In the above example the $bio variable has the correct value assigned to it - it has the correct text that the user submits, but for some reason it's not getting updated.  If I make it an INSERT query (and add data for a full new record), the content of the biography field in the DB is there - in other words, it works correctly for INSERT but not UPDATE.

Comment: Tried it - same result.  It seems like it could be some mysql setting or something like that. I've never experienced this before...

Comment: What is in your `$db->bind('bio', $cleanBio);` function code

Comment: Posted $db class above. I updated the orig code to reflect the exact use of the db class (had simplified before).
NOTE: I can run the query without PDO, objects, etc. - just a straight update query with basic procedural php - and I get the same result (the empty blob)

Comment: Tried it - didn't change the result.

Just pulled this out of the mysql log though:
89 Query     UPDATE clients
SET bio = 'this is a test string', bio_approved = 'z', readiness='z'
WHERE client_index = 6

91 Query     UPDATE clients
SET bio = '', bio_approved = 'z', readiness='z'
 client_index = 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93760/discussion-between-mitul-and-xmy).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was something going on on the server where it was reloading the page almost as soon as it was originally loaded and the variable in $_POST for the bio would be empty but other form data passed would not (haven't tracked down why that is...).

Once I figured this out, the empty field resolved itself, though why this was happening is still under investigation.  Sorry for the red herring and thank you for your help!